# Passing MainActivity in params

Tags: android, parameters, android-asynctask, applicationcontext

I need to start AsyncTask in UI thread, but the Constructor has (MainActivity parentActivity)
parametr. I don't really understand why it should be implemented and how I must pass it.

Here Eclipse says "Cant resolve MainActivity to a variable." Same for Activity.MainActivity.

```
new DownloaderTask(MainActivity).execute();`
```

And the constructor.

```
public DownloaderTask(MainActivity parentActivity) {
    super();

    mParentActivity = parentActivity;
    mApplicationContext = parentActivity.getApplicationContext();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line...

```
new DownloaderTask(MainActivity).execute();
```

to this...

```
new DownloaderTask(MainActivity.this).execute();
```

And you are passing `Context` of `MainActivity` not the activity...so in `DownloaderTask()` constructor, the parameter will be `Context` type not `MainActivity`...The constructor should look like as below...

```
public DownloaderTask(Context context) {
    super();

    mApplicationContext = context;

}
```

Comment: Yeah! Thats what I thought about, but this programm is actually a task with missing blocks of code. And this constructor is already written and I must not change it. So i pass an instance and then get context already in the constructor.

Comment: can you post your full `AsyncTask`? so that I can help you more? and I trying to figure out the problem by passing an `MainActivity` instance...thats working fine for me.

Comment: Looks like AsyncTask activity is working now. But i got problems with the receiver. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22051532/receiver-not-registered

Answer (score 0):

you can call like following if you are calling **directly** from the MainActivity

```
new DownloaderTask(this).execute();
```

or if you are callling from an **inner class** you can call like

```
new DownloaderTask(MainActivity.this).execute();
```