# Can Android call Activity#onPause without Activity#onResume, or can Context#registerReceiver fail?

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I have the following crash on a SAMSUNG-SGH-I337 running 4.4.2:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.example/com.example.activities.MyActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: com.example.activities.MyActivity$1@42b51940
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3248)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3203)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3181)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:161)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1276)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: com.example.activities.MyViewActivity$1@42b51940
    at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:671)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1798)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:501)
    at com.example.activities.MyViewActivity.onPause(MyViewActivity.java:165)
    at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:5530)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1251)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3234)
    ... 12 more
```

I only register my `BroadcastReceiver` inside `MyActivity#onResume` and I only unregister inside `MyActivity#onPause`.

Basically, it seems like `onPause` was called without a corresponding `onResume`, or `Activity#registerReceiver` failed for some reason.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    myFilter = new IntentFilter("myIntent");
    myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        }
    };
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(myReceiver, myFilter);

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
    super.onPause();
}
```

This seems similar to [Receiver not registered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22051532/9636), but that was caused by the author not creating their `BroadcastReceiver`, and as you can see, I definitely create mine.

Comment: Does this happen even if you initialize `myReceiver` in `onResume()` instead of `onCreate()`?

Comment: I've only seen this crash once, so I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google seems to think this is a Samsung-only problem.](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=74464#c3) So, I might just need to workaround it by catching the `IllegalArgumentException` in `onPause`.

Comment: I'm having the same with Fragment#oncreate-ondestroy on sony xperia too.

Comment: I also see NPEs reported on Samsung devices when the variable is assigned in onResume() and referenced in onPause().